# How to prove determinant for second order tensors?

Tags: tensors, index-notation

I was asked in an exam to prove the following expression,
$$ \det(A) = \dfrac16 \epsilon_{ijk}\epsilon_{lmn}A_{il}A_{jm}A_{kn}$$
I know that it can be written in the following form,
$$ \det(A) = \epsilon_{ijk}A_{i1}A_{j2}A_{k3}$$
I don't know how to proceed beyond it.

Will someone please help me, Thank you.

Comment: What is the definition of the determinant you are used to? Keep in mind that $\epsilon_{ijk}$ is precisely the sign of the permutation sending $1,2,3$ to $i,j,k$ when such a permutation exists, and is $0$ otherwise.

Comment: See uses of the Levi-Civita symbol $\epsilon_{ijk}$ in (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol)

Answer (score 1):

RHS:
$$\frac 1 6 ϵ_{ijk} ϵ_{lmn} A_{il} A_{jm} A_{kn} \\
= \frac 1 6 ϵ_{ijk} [e_l, e_m, e_n] A_{il} A_{jm} A_{kn} \\
= \frac 1 6 ϵ_{ijk} [A_{il} e_l, A_{jm} e_m, A_{kn} e_n] \\
= \frac 1 6 ϵ_{ijk} [e_i A, e_j A, e_k A] \\
= \frac 1 6 ϵ_{ijk} ϵ_{ijk} \det(A) \\
= \frac 1 6 \, 6 \det(A) \\
= \det(A)$$
with $[a,b,c]$ being the vector product of $a,b,c$.